# Wordpress limit post that subscriber can create

Tags: posts

Hi my wordpress users are able to submit posts. But I want to limit the number of posts that they can submit. Can you help me?

I already tried https://wordpress.org/plugins/bainternet-posts-creation-limits/ and https://cs.wordpress.org/plugins/wpsite-limit-posts/ but they dont work.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: By default, subscribers can't create posts at all so, first off, how was that hacked into place?

Answer (score 5):

This solution uses the [publish post hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post). What's happening here is that when a post is published, it runs the custom `post_published_limit` function we create below.

The $max_posts is set statically here, you can expand it to pull the value from elsewhere, but that's beyond the scope of the question being asked. However there is [plenty](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API) of [literature](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) describing how to do that.

The function then gets the count of posts of the author currently trying to publish.

If the $count exceeds the $max_posts the function will save it as a draft instead of publishing it.

```
function post_published_limit( $ID, $post ) {
    $max_posts = 5; // change this or set it as an option that you can retrieve.
    $author = $post->post_author; // Post author ID.
    $count = count_user_posts( $author, 'post'); // get author post count

    if ( $count > $max_posts ) {
        // count too high, let's set it to draft.
        $post->post_status = 'draft';
        wp_update_post( $post);
    }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_limit', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: how to customize it so that it works for the subscriber and for custom post type? thank you very much